# MySql Get top n in each group

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query which is like :

```
select title, userId, created_at, deviceCode, streamTimeInSecond
from ( select title, userId, created_at, deviceCode, streamTimeInSecond,
          @userId_rank:=IF(@current_userId = userId, @userId_rank + 1, 1) as userId_rank, 
          @current_userId:=userId 
   from ViewforfirstfiveMovies order by userId, streamTimeInSecond desc ) ranked
where userId_rank<=5;
```

In this query I am trying to get 5 titles viewed by each userId present in database.
Problem: I am getting more than 5 records for few users.

Kindly help me with this problem.

Comment: That looks like it should work to me, and I abuse session variables in that manner regularly. Perhaps the fact that, as the table name suggests, you are using a view is playing havoc with the interaction of the ORDER BY and session variables? I believe MySQL tries to integrate VIEWs into queries using them, to prevent such things as a view selecting all the rows of the table when an accompanying where would limit the results to just a few.

Comment: Ah, are you actually initializing your session variables?

Comment: Thanks.
Actually group by messed everything. Just as I removed it, my query worked fine.

Comment: GROUP BY? That wasn't even in the query posted.

Comment: Sorry... Order By caused me problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select`.  For that reason, you should only set inter-related variables in a single expression.

I would write this as:

```
select title, userId, created_at, deviceCode, streamTimeInSecond
from (select title, userId, created_at, deviceCode, streamTimeInSecond,
              (@userId_rank := if(@current_userId = userId, @userId_rank + 1,
                                  if(@current_userId := userId, 1, 1)
                                 )
               ) as userId_rank,
      from ViewforfirstfiveMovies cross join
           (select @current_userId := 0, @userId_rank := 0) params
      order by userId, streamTimeInSecond desc
     ) ranked
where userId_rank <= 5;
```

In addition, you should set the variables in the same statement.